# AngularJS ngRoute is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have forur files:

```
angularjs.js
scripts.js
ngroute.js
index.html
```

Now, I hav configured the following route:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/author/add", {
            controller : "AuthorController",
            templateUrl : "view2.html"
        })
        .when("/author/show", {
            controller : "AuthorController",
            templateUrl : "view1.html"
        })
        .otherwise("/", redirectTo : "/author/add")
});
```

And here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ngroute.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js" ></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    <div data-ng-controller="AuthorController">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="single in authors">
           Author {{ single.author }} has written {{ author.book }}
        </ul>
    </div>
<a href="#/author/add">Add New Author</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click on author/add href link, it does not load the view. Even the above routeConfig code cause the rest of js script to stop working. There is a problem in the block, but I can't figure out what it is!

Comment: What does your browser's console say?

Comment: And where did you put your `viewX.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the `otherwise` part. Change your route config to:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/author/add", {
            controller : "AuthorController",
            templateUrl : "view2.html"
        })
        .when("/author/show", {
            controller : "AuthorController",
            templateUrl : "view1.html"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : "/author/add"})
});
```